# How to compare dates in 2 different columns and then remove the row if one date is later than the other in r/

Tags: r

I have a data set of cases, when patients were registered and when they had blood test results.

I only want to get the blood test result which were made are less than a year after they registered for the trial.

The registration date is unique to each person.

```
data2=data1[!(data1$START.DATE> data1$READING.DATE),]
```

This is as close as I can can think to get but it doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

A reproducible example would help get to an answer quicker.

This might work:

```
data2 <- data1[data1$START.DATE - data1$READING.DATE < 365, ]
```